# Why doesn't Dead Space 3 restart in the same place after I quit the game?

Tags: dead-space-3

I'm having trouble saving with my XBOX 360 with Dead Space 3. I'll play a lot, then I'll save and quit. When I come back it puts me way back, nowhere near where I saved. I tried clearing my cache, and it seemed to happen after I did the update on line

Comment: Yes, it's a pain. Last time I saved after a difficult fight and entering a new chapter. And today I loaded and the save sent me back to the fight.

Answer (score 9):

This is how the game is designed to work. When doing a save and quit, it saves your inventory (and presumably quest progress) but not your current location. Saving of the location you start at seems to be basically checkpoint-based in my experience.

Comment: Yep, the physical location you return to is a checkpoint just like the console versions. The PC version is basically a port, and there's no "quicksave" style functionality

Comment: Actually it says it's saving inventory when you hit save and quit but it doesn't save anything, not even your quest progress. I've been looking it up cause it seems like a glitch but no luck.

Comment: This is how DS1&2 worked on PC.

Comment: Actually, I guess what he means is sometimes you're halfway through a string of fights and you get stuck in one area, so you decide to take a break. When you resume, you're not at the checkpoint you'd been resuming from earlier after dying, but at the start of the string of fights again. I've experienced this too, it's a real pain on Impossible mode :(

Answer (score 1):

If you just quit it will just save your inventory. Try checking if theres the save symbol in the upper right corner (autosave, which saves your location) so you know when you are safe to quit without having to start at another location again.

Answer (score -1):

The game saves your mission progress when "saving progress" indicator is displayed on-screen (there are also checkpoint-related saving notifications). If you quit the game when the notification has just been displayed your character resumes from the exact same point.

I only have experience with the PC version. Saving behavior may have been tweaked in updates and the existing answers may have been correct at the time of posting.

Comment: None of the existing questions tell that "saving progress" indicates a save point. Unknown reason of downvoting.